# How to split the address in google map in search textbox?

Tags: google

I have created visual force pages it's working fine. I need to spilt the selected address such as city, street, country and so on. Please find the VF page attachment of images.

```
<apex:page id="page" standardController="account" >
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en&sensor=false&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function initializeField() {        
            var input = document.getElementById('page:form:field');           
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input); 


            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        draggable:true,
        title: address


        });

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeField);  

    </script> 
<apex:form id="form" ><b> <apex:outputLabel value="Global Address Search" for="field" /></b>&nbsp;
<apex:inputTextarea id="field" cols="25" rows="5" />
 </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

Images:

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Inside the address in Global Address Search it split in separate related text box.I am not able to send images. I exactly trying to this URL output. Please check :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Comment: @Nikitha If my solution answers your question, can you please mark it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to replicate your example URL in visual force. It is working as shown in the screenshots. You can update further as per your requirement.

**Screen 1**

[image]

**Screen 2**

[image]

**VF page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script> 
    <apex:form id="searchform" >
        <apex:pageBlock id="searchblock">
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="searchblocksection" columns="3" title="Address Search" >
                <apex:outputLabel  value="Global Address Search" for="field" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
                <apex:inputtextarea label="" cols="50" rows="5" id="addressfield" onfocus="geolocate()"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="addressblocksection" title="Address details" columns="2">
                <apex:inputText label="Street No" id="street_number"/>
                <apex:inputText label="Street Address" id="route"/>
                <apex:inputText label="City" id="locality"/>
                <apex:inputText label="State" id="administrative_area_level_1"/>
                <apex:inputText label="Zip code" id="postal_code"/>
                <apex:inputText label="Country" id="country"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>  
        // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
        // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

        var autocomplete;
        var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            locality: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
        };

        function initialize() {
            // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
            // to geographical location types.
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
                (document.getElementById('{!$Component.searchform.searchblock.searchblocksection.addressfield}')), {
                    types: ['geocode']
                });
            // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
            // populate the address fields in the form.
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                fillInAddress();
            });
        }

        // [START region_fillform]
        function fillInAddress() {
            // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            for (var component in componentForm) {
                //document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                //document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            // Get each component of the address from the place details
            // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                    var elem_id = '{!$Component.searchform.searchblock.addressblocksection.}'+":"+addressType;
                    document.getElementById(elem_id).value = val;
                }
            }
        }
        // [END region_fillform]

        // [START region_geolocation]
        // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
        // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
        function geolocate() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        center: geolocation,
                        radius: position.coords.accuracy
                    });
                    autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                });
            }
        }
        // [END region_geolocation]
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){ 
            initialize();
        };
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @Nikitha If it was the answer can you please mark it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Man! this is such a cool solution. *Very* well done.